# how to restrict pages in Django? if "@login required(login_url='login')" does not work

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, django-project-architect

I'm working on this signup-login project in Django and i want to restrict home page.. but for some reason this code is not working for me.. can you tell me why? and is there any other way to restrict pages in Django?
*@login_required(login_url='login')*

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def index(request):
   all_members = {}
   return render(request, "HTML/index.html",{'Members': all_members})
```

Comment: what do you mean `not working`?

Comment: idk it just does not restrict any page for me

Comment: try to clear browser cache for the `index` page, and refresh.

Comment: still its not working..

Comment: Try to use reverse on the login url

Comment: how can i do that? like this 'return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated: #if the user is not authenticated
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login")) #redirect to login page
else:
    #code
```

And in terms of your code, have you included:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```